# Shiny DT: selectColumns not working?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the following example app (code below). The idea is that if a user selects the second column (index of 1), the selection goes to the third column (index of 2), as I don't want the user to be able to select the second column at all (as far as I know there is no built-in way to stop the user selecting a particular column in DT).

The issue is that while `selectRows(tableProxy, c(2)` works (a trivial example of a row selection), `selectColumns(tableProxy, c(2))` only deselects the currently selected column and does not select the third column.

Is there an issue with my syntax, or is this a bug? If it is a bug, is there a workaround?

Reproducable example:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    tags$div(title = "Iris table",
             DT::dataTableOutput("irisTable"))
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a table
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$irisTable <- DT::renderDT(datatable(head(iris, 20), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE),
  rownames = FALSE, 
  selection = list(target = 'row+column', mode='single', selected = list(rows = c(NULL), cols = c(2)))
  ) %>% 
    formatStyle(0, target= 'row',color = 'black', 
                lineHeight='70%', padding = '3px 3px', fontSize = '80%')
  )

  tableProxy <- dataTableProxy("irisTable")

  observeEvent(input$irisTable_columns_selected, {
    if (input$irisTable_columns_selected == 1) {
      #tableProxy %>% selectColumns(2)
      selectRows(tableProxy, c(2))
      selectColumns(tableProxy, c(2))
    }
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Update: I have tried the above with the example code published [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-proxy/) (converted to work with a single file Shiny app), and I have the same issue. I've reinstalled the DT package and it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of DT that should have been fixed via the PR [rstudio/DT#528](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/528). You can install the dev version to test it by calling `devtools::install_github("rstudio/DT")`.

Comment: Thank you, I had given up on this one. Looking forward to getting it to work.